# GPS module not showing useful information using Arduino

Tags: arduino, gps, android-gps, nmea

I have connected the GPS module with Arduino board, however, when I open the serial monitor, it shows a lot of empty fields and zeros. Is the GPS module faulty?

It shows this :

```
$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E
$GPRMC,000053.799,V,,,,,0.00,0.00,060180,,,N*43
$GPVTG,0.00,T,,M,0.00,N,0.00,K,N*32
$GPGGA,000054.799,,,,,0,0,,,M,,M,,*4E
$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E
$GPRMC,000054.799,V,,,,,0.00,0.00,060180,,,N*44
$GPVTG,0.00,T,,M,0.00,N,0.00,K,N*32
$GPGGA,000055.799,,,,,0,0,,,M,,M,,*4F
$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E
```

Comment: The answer notwithstanding (and he's right about time to gain fix), how could we possibly know if your module is faulty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All this means is that your GPS doesn't have a fix yet.

A cold start on a GPS can take several minutes (like, up to 7 or so) to get its initial fix.  Make sure the antenna is out in the open with a clear view of the sky.

Also, obviously, if your GPS unit has an external antenna, make sure it's connected properly.  Those small coaxial connectors break easily!